# Ionic (V4) Ionic serve - white screen with property display:none in core.css

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

ionic version 4.12.0
cordova version 8.1.2

Application got stuck on white screen after ionic serve. No error on console if I remove this from core.css application got normal but child view doesn't appear.

```
on-route,
ion-route-redirect,
ion-router,
ion-select-option,
ion-nav-controller,
ion-menu-controller,
ion-action-sheet-controller,
ion-alert-controller,
ion-loading-controller,
ion-modal-controller,
ion-picker-controller,
ion-popover-controller,
ion-toast-controller,
.ion-page-hidden,
[hidden] {
  /* stylelint-disable-next-line declaration-no-important */
 display: none !important;
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear error but you can try execute **ionic repair** command. This maybe will solve your problem.